# How to get the list of windows administrators from a remote machine using WMI client for Python?

Tags: python, wmi, wmi-query

I am writing a Python script to retrieve the list of administrators users from a remote Windows box using the WMI client (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/1.4.9). This is the code I am using:

```
import wmi

wql = r'SELECT * FROM Win32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent="Win32_Group.Domain=\"MY_MACHINE\",Name=\"Administrators\""'
host = '10.253.6.38'
domain = 'My_Domain'
user = 'My_User'
auth_user = '{0}\{1}'.format(domain, user)
password = 'Secret

wmic = wmi.WMI(host, user=auth_user, password=password)
admins_list = wmic.query(wql)
```

But when I try running the query I get an exception with this error:

```
com_error: (-2147217385, 'OLE error 0x80041017', None, None)
```

I cannot find anywhere what that error means. If I run the exact same script but I use another query like for example `SELECT PartComponent FROM Win32_SystemUsers`, it works fine. To make it more strange, if I run the same query that is giving me problems directly in the remote machine using the "WMI Tester" it works perfectly. I have spent more than 2 days trying to make this work with no luck, I've run out of ideas. If anyone knows what is going on I could use some help here. thanks.